# Font Size Difference between Printer Canvas and Form Canvas

Tags: windows, delphi, printing, delphi-7

I use

```
Printer.BeginDoc;
Printer.Canvas.Font := Self.Font;
Printer.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Verdana';
Printer.Canvas.Font.Size := 10;
Printer.Canvas.TextOut(10,0,'Nom : Prenom Nom');
Printer.Canvas.TextOut(10,100,'Nom2 : Prenom2 Nom2');
Printer.EndDoc;
```

Now I wanted to make some kind of preview so decided to make a preview form.
But, I have to set the font size a lot bigger.

```
Form2.Canvas.Font := Self.Font;
Form2.Canvas.Font.Name := 'Verdana';
Form2.Canvas.Font.Size := 25;  //<=======Have to set this a lot higher to resemble what is on the print.
Form2.Canvas.TextOut(10,0,'Nom : Prenom Nom');
Form2.Canvas.TextOut(10,100,'Nom2 : Prenom2 Nom2');
```

How come the font size doesn't behave the same on the printer.canvas and form.canvas?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting? And what do you experience?

Comment: I was expecting that if I printed to a canvas, it didn't matter if it was a canvas on screen or a printer canvas. So I was expecting to show the same. (a bit bigger on screen because a screen has a lower resolution as a printer)

Comment: And just when I decide to ask the question I find a solution: Form2.Canvas.Font.PixelsPerInch:=Printer.Canvas.Font.PixelsPerInch (after a begindoc to initialize the printer.)

Comment: @PieterB on screen, you usually have 96DPI IIRC, while on the printer 300+

Comment: @ComputerSaysNo yes, I was confused, because when printing pixels, shapes or for positioning on a canvas Delphi takes absolute values regardless of dpi, but the fonts get automatically scaled depending on dpi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this occur because depends of printer DPI, for example

> the Printer.Canvas.Font.Size := 8 works on a printer with 300 DPI a
> printer with 600 DPI needs .Size := 4 for the same result.

try this before Printer.beginDoc

```
Printer.Canvas.Font.PixelsPerInch := GetDeviceCaps(Printer.Handle,LOGPIXELSY);
```

or try this function always you need to change font size:

```
procedure TForm1.SetPixelsPerInch;
var
 FontSize: integer;
begin
  FontSize := Printer.Canvas.Font.Size;
  Printer.Canvas.Font.PixelsPerInch := GetDeviceCaps(Printer.Handle,LOGPIXELSY);
  Printer.Canvas.Font.Size := FontSize;
end;
```

See more details in http://www.delphigroups.info/2/e7/314459.html